# Capturar valores de columnas ocultas de un datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Sé que hay otros foros con esta pregunta, pero he intentado las opciones que dicen pero no me funciona. Necesito capturar los valores de una columna no visible de un datatable

```js
var dtTable = $('#tabla1').DataTable({
  "columns": [{
      "data": null,
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
        return meta.row + 1; // La columna 0 ahora contendrá el número consecutivo
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_NAME"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_TYPE_NAME"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_STATUS_NAME"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_BENEFICIO"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_FCLOSE"
    },
    {
      "data": "NOMBRE",
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_ARTICULOID"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_AIM"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_SPONSOR"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_CANTAIM"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_SENDC"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_COSTE"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_COSTR"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_ANSWERID"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_ESALES"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_SALES"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_ANSWERE"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_ANSWER"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_RINVERSION"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_INVERSION"
    },
    {
      "data": "CAMPAIGN_NOTES"
    },
    {
      "data": "idComercial"
    },
    {
      "data": null,
      "orderable": false
    }
  ],
  columnDefs: [{
      targets: -1,
      className: 'dt-body-center',
      "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonEditar'><span class='icon-edit1'></span></button>",
      data: null
    },
    {
      targets: 7,
      visible: false
    },
    {
      targets: 8,
      visible: false
    },
    //... 
    {
      targets: 22,
      visible: false
    }
  ],
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla1" class="display" style="width:100%">
```

Desde el botón de editar quiero capturar todos los datos inclusive los ocultos pero sólo logro capturarlos los visibles:

```
var rowData = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
var id_campaign = rowData[22];
```

### Intentos

He intentado

```
var valor = $('td:visible', this).eq(3).text();, var valor = dtTable.row(this).data()[3];,var valor = dtTable.row(this).data()[3];
```

pero con ninguno me funciona... Ayuda

Comment: He convertido tu código en snippet, agrega los datos que creas relevantes para tener un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Después de ingresar a varios foros, por fin encontré la solución:

```
var dtTable = $('#tabla1').DataTable();
var rowIndex = dtTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).index();
var rowData = dtTable.row(rowIndex).data();

//Ejemplo de como capturar los valores
var arrayComerciales = rowData['idComercial'];
var idComerciales = arrayComerciales.split(',');
$('#salesmanCampaign').selectpicker('val', idComerciales);
$('#salesmanCampaign').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Con el anterior código, puedo no sólo capturar los valores de las columnas ocultas sino las visibles. Espero les sirva para otros que puedan estar experimentando mi falla.